# Desktop computer loses wi-fi connection, when I connects to it an Android device by usb cable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb, android

I have a desktop computer with a wireless (usb dongle) adapter, Android phone and a router.

The computer identifies the WI-FI net from the router (via wireless usb dongle adapter) , and I can surf.

Then I connect the phone to the same computer by a USB cable (The reason I'm doing it, is that I want to debug an Android application).

At the moment I connect the phone, the computer no longer identify the network, although the network exists (The Android phone identifies it).

Does someone have any idea why, and what can I do about it? Appreciate any help.

Comment: What is your operating system? What is the output of `ipconfig /all` before and after connecting the phone? Does the wireless come back when you disconnect your phone? Is your phone set up to provide USB tethering? Please [edit] your question to provide this information.

Comment: That's just wierd. USB 3.0?

Comment: @ Journeyman I wrote how the problem was solved, but I need to wait 2 days before I check it as 'solved'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved in a very simple way  - I tried to connect the phone to an other usb socket.
The one which caused the disconnection was in the front of the computer, and the one which didn't cause any disconnection, was in the back of the computer.

Hope it will help someone.